# How to enable emojis in custom Keyboard in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, emoji

I am trying to make a custom keyboard like below:

[image: This is the Image for custom Keyboard]

This is the custom keyboard that I have made but I do not know how to access emoji in that. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the unicode values in order to display emojis in views.

```
lbl.text = String(format: "%C", 0xe04f)
```

Here is a reference to many of the emoji unicode values.
http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: I have tried but not getting what exactly going on.

Comment: `@IBAction func emojipressed(_ button: UIButton){
       
       
        let utf8str = "0xe04f" // your value coming from quesimage
        
        let emojiStr = String(format: "%C", arguments: [utf8str])
        print(emojiStr) // ⑰
        button.titleLabel!.text = emojiStr
    }
`

Comment: Can you please give any example code which contains normal custo keyboard with emojis @Mark McCorkle